# Facebook app displaying a window, within a window

Tags: html, facebook

I am new to creating apps on facebook, and I have finally figured out how to have my page post to the canvas of my app. The problem is, within the app canvas, it looks its pulling data from the whole window in the canvas. So it looks like a window within the canvas. I need some help trying to get this right, this is my first app! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

check out http://www.facebook.com/BattlegroundKia?sk=app_262444430433288

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your App settings under Page Tab, you are setting your Page Tab URL as the Canvas Page which is wrong.

It should point to your server so it should like like: `https://secure.dealerpro.net/facebook-credit-app.aspx?hostname=www.battlegroundkia.com`

Comment: Thank you for reponding. I changed that, now my canvas is white. Now I wonder if any of my other settings are incorrect. Where does Canvas URL under Canvas point?